# Shall we map opportunity field with out lead field while lead conversion

Tags: opportunity, leads, lead-conversion

I stuck in a place called field mapping in lead conversion.In my organisation while lead conversion picklist(standard) called "Type" in opportunity object.But in my lead object i don't have that picklist.I create that picklist in lead object
and try to map that picklist it is not available in mapping.what are ways to achieve thiis

Answer (score 1):

It has been ages since I grappled with this, but do you have to specify it at all?

If not, then you have some options. You could add the custom field to the Lead object *if it makes sense to your business use case* and then map it accordingly. If you leave the mapping blank, what then? Well, again you have options:

- Create a workflow rule on Opportunity that sets the type based on some other criteria.
- Create a process builder process on Opportunity that does this (and whatever other generated values you want all in one go).
- Use an Opportunity workflow rule to assign a task to someone to review and manually set the type

You could do the above also if you create the Lead "Type" field, too. Set the workflow on Lead instead of opportunity.

There is one final option: go with code. If you don't like the way that lead conversion works at all, there are some who have created their own lead conversion algorithms with Apex. This is always an option.